# systemd path unit with PathExists

Tags: linux, systemd

I've been working on creating a very simple service which monitors a location for the existence of a file and then runs a script. I understand the systemd layout of having my .path unit and a .service unit and I've managed to get it to work. However, I find PathExists really strange. In testing what I have seen is that if I create the file, the unit will trigger. My script then deletes that file. If I create the file again, the unit does not seem to run. If I then delete the file manually and create it again then the unit runs. I've done it over and over and it seems to follow this pattern. I switched to using PathModified and it catches the file each time I create it. However, pretty sure it also run when the file is deleted.

Here are the service files

Path file

```
[Unit]
Description=My app
Wants=myapp.service

[Path]
PathExists=/tmp/pathtofile/file

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And here is the service file

```
[Unit]
Description=My App service file

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=-/path/to/my/script/script.sh param1
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what exactly does the service file you are using look like?

Comment: @thrig added the file

Comment: Your service will not be triggered if it is already running.

Answer (score 0):

Your files vary from what I got to work though I'm not sure which line(s) in yours are the problematic ones:

```
[root@localhost]~# cat run
#!/bin/sh
date +%s >> /root/run.log
[root@localhost]~# chmod +x run
[root@localhost]~# cat /etc/systemd/system/foo.service
[Unit]
Description=My App service file

[Service]
ExecStart=/root/run
[root@localhost]~# cat /etc/systemd/system/foo.path
[Unit]
Description=My app

[Path]
PathExists=/root/trigger
Unit=foo.service

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
[root@localhost]~# systemctl start foo.path
[root@localhost]~# rm run.log
[root@localhost]~# touch trigger
[root@localhost]~# rm trigger
[root@localhost]~# touch trigger
[root@localhost]~# cat run.log
1658387828
1658387829
```